# What is the game/book where swords power starships?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I'm working to create a fantasy/sci-fi world (for my own nefarious purposes) where swords can power starships.

**I have this vague recollection of having encountered a system like that previously in a book or game. Does anyone have any thoughts or clues as to what this property might be?**

Comment: Refer to [this page](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for guidance on how to write a good story-ID question - you can [edit] any details you remember to your question at any time. As it stands, it's too broad for us to answer.

Comment: Are you thinking of the Star of the Guardians series by Margaret Weiss?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you're mis-remembering an [episode of Farscape](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Revenging_Angel) where D'Argo is unable to power his ship until he places his Qualta Blade (a prototypically Luxan weapon) into the designated slot. It wasn't powering the ship per se but it was giving access.

> **D'Argo:** [Translating] *Active self-destruct code can be voided with one of 3... Pre! Pre-determined ah - artifacts singular to Luxan
>   heritage. Ancient Freedom Text. That's very rare. An Orican's Prayer
>   Amulet. This is - hopeless.*
>
> **LuxanShip:** *Ahfah. Deltoh. **Qualta blade.***

[image]

Comment: hhmm, could be. The images in my head don't seam to match the Farscape ascetic though.